# Change Wifi state on Android only if user changed

Tags: android

I have a program that scans and lists the phone's wifi periodically.
With android version API >= 18 I can easily get those without turning on the wifi.

The problem, when the version is less than 18 is when the user:

- Set wifi off: I have to turn wifi on, scan and then turn off again.
- Set wifi on: I don't need to turn it off again.

I tried register a BroadcastReceiver that listens to WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION but how can I know if it was me that changed the wifi state or the user?

Comment: How do **you** change the state of the WiFi in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement that kind of behavior by extending a `BroadcastReceiver` that will "listen" for custom events that **you** create.

No matter what you do, the system will broadcast the `WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`, so what you're going to do is broadcast a custom intent that you create and have it captured by a `BroadcastReceiver`  when the wifi state is changed from **within** your application.

Have the `BroadcastReceiver` listen only for your broadcast and then in the `onReceive()` method of the broadcast receiver activate the WiFi.

Comment: I implemented this, but the problem still remains, I connect and disconnect within my application ok, but how do I know if the user pressed the button, or my application did the disconnect?

Comment: You will know when the user pressed the button because when the button is pressed your event will be broadcasted and you will handle it in your broadcastreceiver, and **in** the broadcast receiver you will activate the WiFi. You will not have a broadcast receiver listening for the system-wide `WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` but a local broadcast receiver listening to the action that your button fires up.

Comment: The user don't press any button in my event, that's the thing, periodically it turns on the wifi to scan and then has to leave it to its original state, that workflow of yours won't work.

Comment: Let us work this out, can you please share the code that you periodically turn on the wifi to scan? And we'll see step by step if we can make this work out.

Comment: It's on [github](http://github.com/enriquefynn/datagather-client) The file is the [Logger](https://github.com/enriquefynn/datagather-client/blob/master/app/src/main/java/research/ufu/datagather/activities/Logger.java). It is not functioning well, and it's not so pretty (just for a simple project) But I tried your approach, in **sendBroadcast(getWifiStatus)**; It's where I try to change the status of the wifi and in **registerReceiver(... , intentFilter)** is where I may change back the status in case it was already on. This event gets the wifi scan result; Thanks;

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem please accept it as an answer. Thanks.